# Pagination in Codeigniter with join

Tags: codeigniter

I had my pagination working but then the structure of the database changed so it now doesn’t work because I have to join two tables to get the results I once had…

My db script is:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*');
$query = $this->db->from('user_entry'); 
$query = $this->db->join('user_details', 'user_entry.UserID = user_details.id'); 
$query = $this->db->limit($limit, $offset); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

If you could help me, I would be so grateful - thanks.

Comment: You need to give us more information that you are giving us. `What chaned in the database?`. `what doesn't work?`

Comment: Ah sorry - I changed the database by splitting the table in to two tables...so now I have the entry and the details tables. So when I do the join in codeigniter the pagination just doesn't work at all now. :(

Answer (score 0):

I still don't think there's enough information.. but pagination needs to know the total rows in order to create the links. Assuming this code is in your model and you're calling the model function from your controller in order to set the pagination config variables:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user_entry');
$this->db->join('user_details', 'user_details.id = user_entry.UserID');
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->num_rows();
```

in your controller:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yoururl.com/controller/function';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->model_name->function(); // Model and function to the code above
$config['per_page'] = 10; // # of results you want to display per page
$config['num_links'] = 10; // # of pagination links you want to display
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

in your view where you want the pagination displayed:

```
<?=$this->pagination->create_links();?>
```